# Python Requests How to properly use the payload of a post request

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

What am I doing wrong? I have scraped websites before but this payload is proving difficult for me.

[image]

```
from requests import session
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

payload = {
    "p_flow_id" : 838 ,
    "p_flow_step_id": 4 ,
    "p_instance" :1282563643133 ,
    "p_page_submission_id" :4990502617229,
    "p_request" : ""
 }


with session() as c:
     c.post('http://nid.usace.army.mil/cm_apex/f?p=838:4:0::NO/wwv_flow.accept', data=payload)
     url = c.get('http://nid.usace.army.mil/cm_apex/f?p=838:4:0::NO/wwv_flow.accept')
     html = url.content 
     soup = bs(html)
```

Comment: You might wanna add try/except to check if the request returns 200 or not, and handle an exception if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Your first request returns  with 404 error:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

payload = {
    "p_flow_id" : 838 ,
    "p_flow_step_id": 4 ,
    "p_instance" :1282563643133 ,
    "p_page_submission_id" :4990502617229,
    "p_request" : ""
    }


with session() as c:
     print 'in' 
     r1 = c.post('http://nid.usace.army.mil/cm_apex/f?p=838:4:0::NO/wwv_flow.accept', data=payload)
     print r1.status_code  # 404
     url = c.get('http://nid.usace.army.mil/cm_apex/f?p=838:4:0::NO/wwv_flow.accept')
     html = url.content 
     soup = bs(html,'lxml')
     print soup
```